# Rotating images with PHP reduces quality especially over about 10-20 actions

Tags: php, image, image-processing, image-rotation

I am using this code below to rotate my jpeg images, the problem is that after around 10-20 times of rotating the image the image is dramatically lower quality, especially blue skies and such, my question is how can I keep these images the same high quality image? There must be a way. I mean, i keep the original image on the server for each image uploaded, and I don't do anything to that, so if need be it, I guess I could always come up with some way of using that over whenever possible.. But would rather not have to.

```
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

$rotate = imagerotate($source, 90, 0);

imagejpeg($rotate, $filename ,100);
```

Comment: Why are you rotating it "10-20 times"? Can't you just sum all needed rotations and perform them in one go? (I've had better luck using ImageMagick than gd.)

Comment: Well, I have a photo editor for users to edit their images, and they can rotate them, each time they rotate it I have to go through this code, in order to be able to properly get the heights and widths of the image to recalculate max heights and such for the photo viewer with jquery. I have previously asked a question about that, but was unable to get any working solutions. In addition to that reason, I also want the effects to "save" immediately, without having to save or anything. But even without doing it about 10 times, it reduces the quality (especially of blue skies) a bit with just one.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to rotate the source image every time rather than the rotated image?

Comment: well, I have about 8 different sized images of each image (thumbnails for different parts of the website), so I would have to have multiples of all of those and everything, but that reason aside, I'm not sure how I would be able to get the position of the rotated image vs the original in order to continue rotating it by 90 degrees.

Comment: Each time the user 'rotates' the image, keep track of the times going clock-wise or so, subtract going the other direction, and then do the math in your php sending the value of 'clockwise rotations' and rotate the original image by `360 % (90 * $clockwise)` or something similar?

Comment: Something like that may work the first time, the problem then would be if say a few minute later after leaving the website the user wants to go back and rotate it again once more, then there's no way of telling what degree it's already at

Comment: If you can use a database, or even an XML files to save the 'edits' the user makes, you can load those and adjust the image based on what they want to do next?  Not sure what type of edits your user's can do, so depending on that would depend on how you can re-create it from the original image.

Comment: Well I do use databases of course yes, and as of right now, the only edit directly to the image that the user can do is rotating, so I suppose storing the rotation in the database is possible, but not entirely something I really want to do :\

Comment: I think that is about the only solution, as constant changes to an image will continually degrade its quality, regardless of the method used to modify it. (It's why, as a photographer, I use raw images where the edits are saved to xml, the image never actually changes until I export it.  After that, I make changes in photoshop as a psd not a jpg with layers over it.  All that is to prevent degradation of quality that would come from replacing a jpg for every edit)

Comment: That's true, I know the more it's edited the more it degrades it, but i was hoping there was a way of reducing the amount it's degraded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is not the rotation, it's the saving in JPEG. JPEG is always lossy, even if set to "100%" quality. In combination with actually changing the image it deteriorates more rapidly. As mentioned in the comments, the only real way to deal with this is to always work from the source image. Keep track of changes that should be applied to the image and apply them all in a stack of transformations at once to the highest quality image available. It helps to have a limited number of things the user can do to the image, like "rotate x degrees", "apply b/w filter", "resize and crop" and apply each in a strict order once.